# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{i}{k(k+1)}$ converges. Find its sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

Show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{i}{k(k+1)}$ converges. Find its sum.

The presence of the $i$ throws me off. Our professor taught us to find $a$ (the first term in the sequence) and $z$ (the multiplier to get the next term). Then find the modulus of z, and if $|z|<1$ then the series converges.

Here $a=\frac{i}{2}$, but I'm struggling to find $z$. I think that $z=i-\frac{i}{K+1}$, but I'm not completely confident in that. Additionally, if that $z$ value is correct would I end up with $\sqrt{0^2+(1-\frac{1}{K+1})^2}$? I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be a variable in there...

Also how should I find the sum?

Comment: $i$ is just a  constant; pull it out of the sum. The answer is $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Kavi Rama Murthy, pull out the constant multiple of $i$ and simply do partial fractions:

$${=i\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)}$$

So you only need to find the answer to the infinite sum in the brackets, and multiply the result by $i$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: This would be how I'd find the sum correct? I can take it from there on that account. What about proving it converges with $|z|<1$? That's what I'm struggling with the most.

Comment: @complexanalysis There's no $z$ in this problem.  What do you mean?